# Prevent specific character input UITextField

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to prevent a space from being entered into a UITextField. I have looked into the replace method, however, that is not exactly what I am looking for. Is there anyway to prevent characters from being entered into a UITextField, i.e., they are entirely ignored?

If it is impossible to prevent characters from being ignored, then what is the next best method to prevent the user from entering a space into a UITextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside ShouldChangeCharacters method, you can prevent specific characters from being entered into a UITextField **textField**

```
textField.ShouldChangeCharacters = (textField, range, replacementString) =>
{
    if (replacementString == " ")
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

The return false statement simply prevents anything from returning if the user enters a space in this example.

You can modify it to prevent whatever characters you need or only allow a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent spaces from being entered on a UITextField:

```
        var frame = new CGRect(10, 10, 300, 30);
        myTextField = new UITextField(frame);
        myTextField.Text = "NoSpacesAllowed";
        View.Add (myTextField);
        myTextField.ShouldChangeCharacters += (myTextField, range, replacement) => { 
            return replacement.Length == 0 || !replacement.Contains (" "); 
        };
```